# Spring Boot -Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-boot

in my controller I have an endpoint:

```
  @GetMapping(value = SUMMARY_URL, produces = "application/json")
    public DailyReportSummary getSummaryOfDailyReports(
            @RequestParam(name = "from", required = false,defaultValue = "10-10-2017 ") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDateTime from,
            @RequestParam(name = "to", required = false,defaultValue = "10-10-2019 ") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDateTime to) {

        List<DailyReport> summary = statisticService.findByDateToSummary(from, to);

        DailyReportSummary dailyReportSummary = new DailyReportSummary(summary);
```

I though that all is ok, but I have this error:

```
   There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
    Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam 

@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '10-10-2017 '; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [10-10-2017 ]
```

What is wrong with this? I trying this solve this, but nothing works.

edit: with deleted iso still errors :(

Comment: Show us the your post request.  Looks like you are passing a badly formatted value for from/to.

Comment: Iso date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` not `DD-MM-YYYY` or `MM-DD-YYYY`. Your default values are in the wrong format. Also if it only is a date why use `LocalDateTime` over `LocalDate`?

Comment: I have no request, just spring taking default values - to avoid my wrong query in browser. I using LocalDateTime, because I have DATETIME in database

Answer (score 4):

Since the pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` doesn't have time part you need to use `LocalDate`

```
@GetMapping(value = SUMMARY_URL, produces = "application/json")
public DailyReportSummary getSummaryOfDailyReports(
        @RequestParam(name = "from", required = false, defaultValue = "10-10-2017") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate from,
        @RequestParam(name = "to", required = false, defaultValue = "10-10-2019") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate to) {
```

Comment: Say that you provide a pattern of for example`@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")`, you would not need to change the type to LocalDate correct? After adjusting the pattern I am still receiving the same error. How would you deal with this if you wish to go by LocalDateTime?